# How to stop google-bot from indexing a folder inside my s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, google-search-console, x-robots-tag

I have an amazon s3 bucket with static website hosting setup + cloudfront.
I have a folder inside the s3 bucket [ example.com/Books ] which contains pdf files.
I've submitted a sitemap in google search console [ which doesn't contain any pdf urls ] , but google is indexing pdf files in the search results.

In the search console I've added a request to remove all the urls from search result with prefix [ example.com/Books/* ] to be removed immediately. I've searched how to stop indexing files and folders and found the I've to add **" X-Robots-Tag: noindex "** as http header meta data. How do I add that to an s3 bucket ? I've added custom metadata to the folder 'Books' **x-amz-meta-X-Robots-Tag: noindex**.

I've read numerous posts where it's written that I shouldn't block the bots from accessing that folder using Robots.txt , as It won't tell the search engines the **"noindex"** http header I've added to that folder. What to do now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use Lambda@Edge function to edit those origin response headers while accessing those files via CloudFront URL. [ custom domain you've connected to your CloudFront distribution ]. From the response HTTP header, we have to remove `x-amz-meta-header-`from the 'keyname' of the user-defined header, So the crawlers will find X-Robots-Tag: noindex as HTTP header while accessing those files and follow its protocols. More information is available [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-ensure-your-files-never-indexed-while-application-abhishek-biswal/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use robots.txt it works for all search engine bots.

**robots.txt** use same file name exactly which i given.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /foldername/
```

Comment: I already did that and also added a removal request in google search console platform for the particular folder prefix. But it didn't help.

Comment: Just check file name same which is given but small mistake in file name and content of file cause issue for not to crawl.